# JavaScript file in a static resource

Tags: javascript, static-resources

I have a two JavaScript (.js) files in a static resource. When I enter the full [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) of a JavaScript file in the browser, https://uknow.cs14.my.salesforce.com/resource/1301087741200/VExpander/easyXDM.packed.js the JavaScript file is displaying whereas if I do https://uknow.cs14.my.salesforce.com/resource/1301087741200/VExpander/VExpander.child.js the JavaScript file is not displaying.

FYI, both of the JavaScript files are in the same static resource. I have updated the VExpander.child.js file. Prior to my update, VExpander.child.js was displaying in the browser.

Is there a reason for not displaying the file?

Comment: can't think of any other reason than either a typo or the file not being present in the zip that you uploaded as static resource..

Comment: @guy I could see the file in the static resource

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that :-)  I found something in the docs, posting an answer now..

Answer (score 2):

The number 1301087741200 is a timestamp corresponding to a version of the static resource. If you are using `$Resource.VExpander` in Visualforce it will automatically output the number of the latest version of the static resource. But if you hard code the number you will still be getting an earlier version of the zip file.

Comment: I think $Resource.VExpander can be used in Visualforce page.But I need it javascript

Comment: All the cross-linking URLs should be relative not absolute and all the referenced files should be in the same zip. That avoids needing the static resource path. But if for some reason you can't achieve that, setup a configuration JavaScript object in your Visualforce page (that can use $Resource, $Page etc) and have your separate JavaScript files depend on that object.

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from the documentation on http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Delivering_Static_Resources_with_Visualforce

> Sometimes developers are tempted to just hard-code the resulting URL
>   (eg: /resource/1235794002000/stylesheet_red) into their Visualforce
>   pages, but when you do this as opposed to using the
>   $Resource.stylesheet_red expression, you are hard-coding the
>   timestamp. In development you may not notice a problem, but in live
>   production, if you ever updated a resource's file, the new version
>   wouldn't start getting served up for around 24 hours or so. So if you
>   were fixing a bug in a JavaScript file for example, you would have to
>   wait a day for the file to become stale in the cache servers until a
>   new copy was pushed out. In other words, never hard-code URLs!

Comment: How to reference static resource (js file present in static resource) in javascript

Comment: See @Keith's response and another hack here: http://jevonearth.blogspot.nl/2011/08/using-static-resources-with-salesforce.html but maybe better to put a new Question on stackexchange to get more attention.